# Timestampz date conversion in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timestampz data that I need to convert to a pacific time date. The format is "2021-11-24T10:00:00+00:00." It is currently stored in UTC time.

I tried =value(left(g2,10)), but the date is not matching up with other records that I have that are already converted in some instances. I also tried =value(left(g2,10)-(8/24)) and it still does not match up.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this work for you: `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"+"),"T"," ")+1/3` or `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"+"),"T"," ")+0`